# Combination of pairs on a team roster

Tags: probability

I have 17 players on a team. What would the formula be to calculate unique pairs on the roster?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: 17p2? I don't think this is right though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 17 choices for the first player in the pair, and, after making that choice, 16 choices for the second player. By the [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product), this means there are $17\times16$ distinct *ordered* pairs of players. If you want to count *unordered* pairs (i.e. you don't want to count $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ as different), note that each unordered pair was counted twice, so you just need to divide the result by two to get $\frac{17\times16}2$. This number is also written $17\choose2$. See [combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

Comment: thank you! It makes sense now that you say it, I thought it was 17p2 but that would also include double pairs, and not just unique, right?

Comment: Right. 17p2=17*16.